# Will leaving 4 batteries in parallel and series drain them?

Tags: batteries

I am making a big project soon, a spider robot, and I will have a total of 4 batteries. 2 batteries will be wired in parallel and 2 in series, and then those 2 packs of 2 each in parallel.I don't want to have to disconnect them every time I use it, but I will if it drains. So my question is straight forward, will leaving the spider off, but the batteries still connected in the circuit, drain the batteries? I can't find it on google. I noticed the batteries get hot when I tested both volts and amps with my multi-meter. So I figured, it is draining. Is it? I hope this isn't a stupid question.

Comment: parallel  drain occurs from mismatched voltages when not in use if the resting voltage differs if separated, while series excess drain if the capacity is lower and/or ESR is higher.  Both demand balanced cells <2% unless protected but  shorter lifespan of series weakest cell influences total capacity when used and in parallel can affect all cells

Comment: Well, the batteries I am using is new and rechargeable. I tested the voltage of them and it is about the same. I got the 3.7 volts at 3000 mAh ones. I could not test the amps for some odd reason. My multimeter was at at 10 Amps, did not read anything. It is a lot more than 3000mAh. Anyways, they should be matched. So if they are matched with less than 2%, it is good then?

Comment: 10A fuse is blown , charge each 100% then record   mV with same fixed load every hour for intended load rate and make a spreadsheet. Dont assume. Then repeat every 50 charge cycles

Comment: So my multi-meter is broken or my batteries isn't charged? It reads the full 3.7 volts and the volts side, so it has to be fully charged. What is mV? The amazon site said it was 3000 mAh. Confused here even more. I guess I just needed an answer to the if they are matched, then they don't drain question?

Comment: Amazon is buyer's risk, no guarantee. You get to hope to receive what they advertise which is poorly defined. If you can't measure on the 10A socket & scale either you are using the meter wrong or the fuse is blown.  "My multimeter was at at 10 Amps, did not read anything. "

Comment: DO NOT EVER attempt to measure the available current from a battery or other power source by connecting a meter set to read Amps directly across the battery - the meter will short-circuit the battery, and excessive current will flow.  Any "measurement" you get this way is meaningless.

Comment: If they dont have C discharge/charge ratings, ask buyer for specs..

Comment: Ok, lessons learned here. I think the fuse on the multi-meter is broken, not the battery fuse. Good news is that multi-meter cost me $7, so no big deal. The voltage side still works though. The real question is why does it have a amp side if it is just going to blow the fuse? Why have it? What is it for then? I am able to test, before the new batteries, 9v battery amp side, now I can't do that. So it is blown. So I think your saying a 9v has less discharge rate then the new rechargeable batteries I got. That is why it blew a fuse when I tested on new ones.

Comment: By the way, this is my new batteries. https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B014867612/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

Comment: The current scales on a meter are intended for measuring the current drawn by a load - you break the circuit to insert the meter - then the load is controlling the current passing through the meter and load, so you can get reasonable readings without damaging anything.

Comment: That is a little confusing to me, kinda new to this, so what exactly did I do wrong? How do I get it to draw by a load and not directly measuring it?

Comment: Draw a diagram of how the batteries are connected. I can't quite figure it out. You say two in series and two in parallel, and then connect them together. It doesn't make any sense. Draw a diagram showing all the batteries.

Comment: Ok, lets say battery 1,2,3,4. I connect batteries 1 and 2 in series. That is pack 1. Then I connect batteries 3 and 4 in parallel. That is pack 2. Each pack (1 and 2) has 2 batteries. Then I connect pack 1 and pack 2 in parallel. So I will double the voltage and triple the amps. I can draw it, but I can't upload it to this site because the picture size is to big.

Comment: You absolutely, positively should not do what you have described. The two series batteries will have a voltage 2x higher than the two parallel batteries. When you put them together, the two series batteries will discharge at high current into the two parallel batteries, and probably over-charge them. This is like a battery self-destruction device.

Comment: Ok, won't do that then. So how do I double voltage and triple the amps or I can double voltage and double amps? I need double voltage and double amps. I can triple amps, but it is not necessary. So how do I do that then?

Comment: You can arrange your 4 batteries as 4s, which provides quadruple voltage. Or you can do 2p2s, which produces double voltage and double amps. Or 4p, which provides quadruple amps. The 's' means series, and the 'p' means parallel. 2p2s means two parallel two series. Which means you take 1 and 2 and put them in series. Then you take 3 and 4 and put them in series. Then you put those two series packs in parallel with each other.

Comment: Ok that makes sense but I still don't understand why I blew a fuse on my multimeter and how to correctly test batteries next time?

Comment: This is unanswerable without a clear illustration. Your description is mostly random and conflicting.

Comment: You can't really test the "amps" of a battery since it depends on many factors. Manufacturers sometimes specify C-rate and sometimes maximum current (A - amps).
Don't ever connect an amp-meter to the poles of a battery since this will create what's known as a short-circuit draining your battery fast (tens or even hundreds of amps depending on the internal resistance of your battery).

Comment: I recommend using an external power supply until your spider is working. Only then will you know how much power it needs and how much weight it can handle.

Comment: Ok, that makes since. I responded to your answer with 1 question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot just wire batteries together at random and expect things not to blow up.

You created two packs.  One has double the voltage of a single battery, one has double the amperage of a single battery.

Then you short-circuit those packs which differ by the voltage of a single battery.  The double-voltage pack will now violently drain into the double-amperage pack.  The double-voltage pack will likely die of over-current while the double-amperage pack will die of over-voltage.

Depending on the kind of batteries, they might melt wires in the process or catch fire.

So now you have your violently reorganising doomsday battery device.  And you put an amperemeter *across* it.  An ideal amperemeter measures the current running through it without causing an external voltage, so its internal resistance is as close to zero as possible, like a piece of thick wire.

So you now use your amperemeter in order to shortcircuit the remnants of your suicide battery pack and drain all the current it can spare in light of your previous abuse.

Which apparently is still more than the fuse of the amperemeter would have tolerated.

Exploding batteries can cause a lot of damage, but they tend to be comparatively affordable unless we are talking really large ones.  I would seriously recommend that you have someone look over your wiring before and while you start hooking it up with *any* power source, or your large project might become a pretty expensive project due to destroyed parts.

Comment: Well, the only problem with my project is power. I need 6A and 7.4 volts of power. I have a thread on the arduino stack exchange explaining the circuit of all the parts and what power I need. Here that forum: http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/34768/arduino-uno-spider-robot-plan      So since the only problem is power, could I do what mkeith suggested, which is put both packs in series and then hook the 2 packs in parallel? I will have a guy from radio shack who has years of running arduino and circuits. He is the only expert I know. He has even built a 3d printer with the arduino.